Counting the Number of Consecutive Values for Each Session ID
I'm working with a student log data. I want to calculate the load time of an assignment.
Let's say I have the following data



id
method
user_xid
session_id
received
ended




1
createActions
2452
96072D7140B214225DD87468C6C74790
2024-07-28 14:39:47.548 -0400
2024-07-28 14:39:47.658 -0400


2
getTutorStrategiesForProblem
2452
96072D7140B214225DD87468C6C74790
2024-07-28 14:39:47.556 -0400
2024-07-28 14:39:47.697 -0400


3
getTutorStrategiesForProblem
2452
96072D7140B214225DD87468C6C74790
2024-07-28 14:39:47.548 -0400
2024-07-28 14:39:47.658 -0400


8
getUser
2452
96072D7140B214225DD87468C6C74790
2024-07-28 14:39:47.199 -0400
2024-07-28 14:39:47.224 -0400




Sometimes getTutorStrategiesForProblem occurs twice, and sometimes three times, and sometimes ten
There are actions between id 3 and id 8
getTutorStrategiesForProblem is not always followed by createActions

What I would like to do is count the load time from getUser to getTutorStrategiesForProblem.
Below is an example of the output I currently get from my query:



id
session_id
user_xid
received
ended
load_time_seconds




324
96072D7140B214225DD87468C6C74790
9867656
2024-07-28 14:39:47.203 -0400
2024-07-28 14:39:47.697 -0400
0.494871


325
96072D7140B214225DD87468C6C74790
9867656
2024-07-28 14:24:32.676 -0400
2024-07-28 14:39:47.697 -0400
915.021871


326
96072D7140B214225DD87468C6C74790
9867656
2024-07-28 14:24:25.620 -0400
2024-07-28 14:39:47.697 -0400
922.077871


327
96072D7140B214225DD87468C6C74790
9867656
2024-07-28 14:24:25.620 -0400
2024-07-28 14:39:47.697 -0400
922.077871


328
0F5893FD209987E6FB2298DB4D777C66
4356247
2024-07-28 13:56:10.466 -0400
2024-07-28 13:56:11.361 -0400
0.895714


329
35498C6A2BAAB9AF06BB7087ECE2F5A0
5462776
2024-07-28 13:48:47.905 -0400
2024-07-28 13:48:48.875 -0400
0.970097



The reason why some of the load_time are too long is because my query is calculating the load time from the first timestamp of the assignment being loaded to the last time that session id appears. However, I want the query to calculate the load time from the first timestamp which is indicated by an action called getActions to the last getTutorStrategiesForProblem.
Below is my current query:

WITH SessionEvents AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        session_id,
        user_xid,
        method,
        received,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY received) AS rn,
        LEAD(received) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY received) AS next_event_time
    FROM 
        logged_requests
    WHERE 
        method IN ('getActions', 'getTutorStrategiesForProblem')
        AND received >= '2024-07-28'
),
StartEvents AS (
    select
        id,
        session_id,
        user_xid,
        received AS received
    FROM 
        SessionEvents
    WHERE 
        method = 'getActions'
),
EndEvents AS (
    select
        id,
        session_id,
        user_xid,
        ended AS end_time
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             id,
             session_id,
             user_xid,
             method,
             ended,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY ended DESC) AS rn
         FROM 
             logged_requests
         WHERE 
             method = 'getTutorStrategiesForProblem'
             AND received >= '2024-07-28'
        ) AS subquery
    WHERE 
        rn = 1
)
SELECT 
    s.id,
    s.session_id,
    s.user_xid,
    s.received,
    e.end_time,
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (e.end_time - s.received)) AS load_time_seconds
FROM 
    StartEvents s
JOIN 
    EndEvents e
ON 
    s.session_id = e.session_id AND s.user_xid = e.user_xid
ORDER BY 
    s.received DESC;

UPDATE: Sometimes session id appears at a different timestamp.

I think you just need some condition aggregation. Since I'm not clear what you want the final output to be this just calculates the relevant start and finish values and appends them to each row:
with session_load_bounds as (
    select *,
        min(case when method = 'getActions' then received end)
            over (partition by session_id) as start,
        max(case when method = 'getTutorStrategiesForProblem' then ended end)
            over (partition by session_id) as finish
    from T
)
select session_id, start, finish
from session_load_bounds
where received between start and finish;


thanks for the query. However, it won't work because sometimes the session id appears at a later timestamp.
